# How to analyze file and know if messy or encrypted or else?

Tags: gratis, linux, software-development, data-analysis

This is a abstract question for me, hope someone can direct me to one lane.

I want to analyze content of file and want to know info like below:

Is the dedup ratio high or low before I run dedup on files? I'm not sure the if dedup ratio can pre-examine. (dedup means de-duplication. it's used to remove the duplication part of files and achieve compress-like function)

I want to know if any tools(like python, C or else) can achieve analyze-like function?

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean by "dedup". Do you mean "Is the file suitable to be compressed?"

Comment: Sounds like "de-duplicate" to me. Maybe an existing tool?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul , I updated. Dedup means one tool to de-duplication and make the duplication part apprear once. It's like compression.

Comment: @Mawg . It's tool right. I wonder if I can pre-check the dedup ratio before I start to dedup? or something like that?

Comment: Although I recommend you on SuperUser to ask here, and it is the best site, you might be interested to know of https://security.stackexchange.com/ For this question, they would probably also recommend you here for this question, but the site is useful to know for future questions

Comment: @Mawg , maybe I can analyze if the data of file is messy? If messy, I can predict it's not efficient after dedup

Comment: If you see anything other than an even distribution of byte values then it is probably not encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fast compressor on the file data; if the compressed size is:

- much smaller than the raw data, then the file would probably benefit from deduplication.
- the same size as the raw data, then the file would probably not benefit from deduplication.

Example code using fast compressor `lzop`:

```
lzop < raw.dat | wc -c raw.dat - | head -n -1
```